# backbone validation how to perform an OR condition based validation

Tags: validation, backbone.js

In my backbone based project, I have a form in which a only one of certain set of input fields is mandatory.  For example, input box where phone numbers are entered, or an uploaded file that contains the phone numbers.

I am trying to use Thedersen backbone validation http://thedersen.com/projects/backbone-validation/.  All the validation patterns and methods seem to be oriented on a per field basis, and not on a combination OR.

Is there a way to write a validator to say that only one of  fields is mandatory?

Comment: I haven't used backbone.validation myself, but from looking at the documentation you can do this by providing a function to the required property http://thedersen.com/projects/backbone-validation/#do-you-support-conditional-validation

Answer (score 2):

You could define a [custom "required" validator](http://thedersen.com/projects/backbone-validation/#adding-custom-validators) for that special case. In that function you could check if at least one option (phone number or file) is given.

Something like this:

```
validation: {
  attribute: {
    required: function(val, attr, computed) {
      return !(val || app.models.phoneFile)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to use a plugin, Backbone has [validation OOTB](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate).

All you need to do is parse the form, store it into your model, and save it. Validation will be run by default.

Example:

```
var Address = Backbone.Model.extend({
  validate: function(attrs, options) {
    if (!attrs.phone1 && !attrs.phone2) {
      return "You must provide at least 1 phone number";
    }
  }
});
```